# Google Drive import Google Docs

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have the following code for getting `DriveContents` of a file in Google Drive. I'm able to import and get `DriveContents` of MS Word, text files, etc but when the file is native to Google (Google Doc, Google Sheets, etc.) i'm not able to get the contents. My code is below:

```
selectedFile.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
        try {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // display an error saying file can't be opened
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not get file contents");
                return;
            }

            // DriveContents object contains pointers
            // to the actual byte stream
            DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String contentsAsString = builder.toString();

            contents.discard(getGoogleApiClient());

            Log.i(TAG, contentsAsString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Whenever I get a Google format file, it simply returns a result that is not a success and shows the error in my logs. How can I get the file contents of those files as well? Is there something special i'm supposed to do?

I'm reading the following documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but I did it the following way. I check in the metadata if it's a Google format (doc, sheets, etc) and if it is, I have an `AsyncTask` that does the below:

```
// accountName is the email address the user used when choosing which account
String scope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getTokenWithNotification(fragment.getActivity(), accountName, scope, null);
```

After doing the above, you can get the file using the API:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

The `token` from the above gives the `Authentication` header token on the downloading. We can export the file as docx, pdf, etc and download it that way.